# How can I get img src using php domxpath

Tags: php, html, curl, domdocument, domxpath

I want to get the img src value using domxpath.

Let us say I have this sample.html page:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="img-wrapper">
            <img src="sample1.jpg"/>
            <p class="title">Sample 1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="img-wrapper">
            <img src="sample2.jpg"/>
            <p class="title">Sample 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="img-wrapper">
            <img src="sample3.jpg"/>
            <p class="title">Sample 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using CURL, DOMDocument and DOMXPath I want to get the img src and the title:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://path/to/sample.html');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($result);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$entries = $xpath->query('//div[@id="wrapper"]/div[@class="item"]');
$results = array();
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    $result = array();
    $result['img'] = $xpath->query("img", $entry)->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $result['title'] = $xpath->query("p[@class='title']", $entry)->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $results[] = $result;
}
return $results;
```

This will result to img as null:

```
[
    {
        "img": null,
        "title": "Sample 1"
    },
    {
        "img": null,
        "title": "Sample 2"
    },
    {
        "img": null,
        "title": "Sample 3"
    }
]
```

Please help me on how to get the img src value. Thank You!

Answer (score 4):

Your XPath in fetching the values isn't quite correct, should be...

```
$result['img'] = $xpath->query("//img/@src", $entry)[0]->value;
$result['title'] = $xpath->query("//p[@class='title']", $entry)[0]->nodeValue;
```

Note the way you get the attributes is by using `@attibuteName`.  Also the `//` at the start allows XPath to find the elements at any point under the start point.

Answer (score 2):

You can get attribute of any DOM element using method `getAttribute('attribute_name')`

Here in your example use `getAttribute('src')`

```
$result['img'] = $xpath->query("//img", $entry)->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
$result['title'] = $xpath->query("//p[@class='title']", $entry)->item(0)->nodeValue;
```